# Program (RackAFX) won't open in clean installs of Windows 7 and Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I have a fresh install of Windows 8.1.  I installed a program 'RackAFX' but it just won't start.  I double click the icon and nothing happens.

I have already installed BOTH the x86 and x64 re-distributables, as mentioned on the RackAFX download page.

Once or twice, Windows reported that 'RackAFX has stopped working' and gave some error codes shown in the following screenshots:

[image: http://i1219.photobucket.com/albums/dd427/Dave_Chambers/64Error_zps2f61e3bd.png]
[image]

I tried all possible 'compatibility' options too and running as administrator but it still won't open.  Now Windows doesn't even give the 'RackAFX has stopped working'.  A double click results in a spinning circle near the mouse and then nothing.

Anyway, trying to debug I installed RackAFX on both my wife's Windows 8.1 machine and my old clogged up Windows 7 partition (on the same machine as the problematic partition) and it works no problem.  I also tried updating Windows 8.1 on the new partition but it still doesn't work.

I then also added another Windows 7 partition to my new hard drive and installed RackAFX but same thing - it won't open.

Not sure if this helps but this SO post describes how to find the LOC related to 'Exception Offset':

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528776/windows-c-is-it-possible-to-find-the-line-of-code-where-exception-was-thrown

So, in summary, RackAFX won't open on a freshly installed Windows 7 or Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the driver for my soundcard hadn't yet been installed and so no default in/out device was selected.  This caused the program to crash.  Installing the driver and choosing an in/out resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing one or more for the MS VC redistributables.

From the RackAFX downloads page:

> 32-Bit Operating Systems
>   If you are not using VisualStudio 2008 and you are installing for the
>   first time please also download and install the VS2008 C++
>   Redistributable x86 (it’s easy, quick and free). If you are going to
>   use VS2008 then you don’t need the Redistributable as it will be
>   installed automatically by VS2008.
>
> 64-Bit Operating Systems If you are installing for the first time
>   please also download and install the VS2008 C++ Redistributable x64
>   (it’s easy, quick and free). You still need this, even if you are
>   planning on using VS2008.
>
> UPDATE: A book reader who is using Win8/64-bit and Visual Studio 2013
>   reports that you need to install BOTH the x86 and x64
>   re-distributables. This is because VS2013 no longer installs some of
>   the required files.